# Append values to a specific range of lists in a list of lists in Python

Tags: python, list

I have a list of lists:

```
length = int(sys.argv[2])
list_of_lists = [[] for _ in range(length)]
```

Then, I need to append data to only a range of lists within list_of_lists. The range of lists I want to modify is extracted fom a file. Here is how I determine the first and last list I need to modify:

```
a_file = open(sys.argv[1])   #open file
for line in a_file:
    field = line.split("\t")   # Separate lines in fields from where I can extract information. 
    start = int(field[0])    # field[0] is the first list within list_of_lists I want to modify.
    end = int(field[1]) # T# field[1] is the last list within list_of_lists I want to modify.
```

to each list in this range, I need to append data that is in field[2]. So I did this:

```
        list_of_lists[start:end].append(int(field[2]))
```

However, it returns an empty list. Could someone help me? Thanks so much in advance!!!

Comment: read [how-to-ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and  [minimal-reproducible-example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Your text and code are inconsistent.  You say, "I need to append data that is in field[2]." but your code says, `append(int(field[3]))`.  Could you be  appending empty field number 3  instead of desired field number 2 or is this just a typo in your question?

Comment: I am sorry, it was a typo in my question. My bad.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could this be what you're looking for:

```
length = int(sys.argv[2])
list_of_lists = [[] for _ in range(length)]

with open(sys.argv[1],'r') as a_file:
    field = a_file.readlines()
    start = int(field[0])
    end = int(field[1])

for index in range(start,end):
    list_of_lists[index].append(field[2])
```